# Log4j MDC with Liferay DXP

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

We would like to implement **Log4j MDC** to log user related info in **Liferay DXP**. So I was trying use Log4j with MDC however there are still dependency issues and I am not sure whether MDC works well with Liferay DXP.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Suyash Bhalekar

Comment: "There are dependency issues" - care to be more specific? What have you tried so far, what did you observe? What did you expect?

Comment: This topic is good to elaborate